# IAS events not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the Infinite AJAX Scroll plugin found here:  http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/overview.html

I have it implemented with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ias = jQuery.ias({
        container : '#customer_photos_wrapper',
        item : '.col-lg-4',
        pagination : '#pagination',
        next : '.next',
        rendered : function(items){
            console.log(items);
        }
    });
});
```

According to the events documentation on the plugins website, rendered should be "Triggered before new items will be rendered."

The next page of items loads correctly when I scroll to the bottom.  However, I'm not getting any sort of output at all from the rendered event.

I tried using the "loaded" event also, but again, no output.  Does anyone know if I am implementing these events the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake.  I see how to properly handle these events now.  Here's what worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ias = jQuery.ias({
        container : '#customer_photos_wrapper',
        item : '.col-lg-4',
        pagination : '#pagination',
        next : '.next'
    }).on('rendered', function(items){console.log(items);});
});
```